# Pointer seems to be getting lost in recursive algorythm

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to do recursive flood fill algorithm and I am passing pointer to some data structure in arguments. At some point into algorithm running ,pointer seems to be lost. I have no idea why.

Code explanation:
first algorythm checks for chunk spill, that means old chunk needs to be saved and new one loaded, based on X and Y. Next thing is replacement of some data in chunk structure and then recursive function calls.

```cpp
bool WorldGenerator::floodFillStep(int _x, int _y, int _target, int _replacement, Chunk* _chunk)
{
    Chunk* chunk = _chunk;
    if (_x < (xSize * CHUNK_WIDTH) && _y < (ySize * CHUNK_HEIGHT))
    {
        int x = _x % CHUNK_WIDTH,
            y = _y % CHUNK_HEIGHT,
            X = _x / CHUNK_WIDTH,
            Y = _y / CHUNK_HEIGHT;

        //check for chunk spill
        if ((floodLastX / CHUNK_WIDTH) < X)
        {
            chunk->save();
            std::string path = "maps/" + std::to_string(X) + std::to_string(Y) + ".map";
            chunk->load(path, X, Y);
        }
        else if ((floodLastY / CHUNK_HEIGHT) < Y)
        {
            chunk->save();
            std::string path = "maps/" + std::to_string(X) + std::to_string(Y) + ".map";
            chunk->load(path, X, Y);
        }
        else if ((floodLastX / CHUNK_WIDTH) > X)
        {
            chunk->save();
            std::string path = "maps/" + std::to_string(X) + std::to_string(Y) + ".map";
            chunk->load(path, X, Y);
        }
        else if ((floodLastY / CHUNK_HEIGHT) > Y)
        {
            chunk->save();
            std::string path = "maps/" + std::to_string(X) + std::to_string(Y) + ".map";
            chunk->load(path, X, Y);
        }
        floodLastX = _x;
        floodLastY = _y;

        //replacement
        if (chunk->getTile(x, y)->getType() == _target)
        {
            if (x < 40 && y < 40 && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
            {
                chunk->getTile(x, y)->setType(_replacement);
                chunk->getTile(x, y)->setMod(255);
                //_chunk->save();

                floodFillStep(_x + 1, _y, _target, _replacement, chunk);
                floodFillStep(_x, _y + 1, _target, _replacement, chunk);
                floodFillStep(_x - 1, _y, _target, _replacement, chunk);
                floodFillStep(_x, _y - 1, _target, _replacement, chunk);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

At some point an exception related to std::vector inside Chunk instance is thrown and when i check local variables, pointer to Chunk is invalid. Any ideas when pointer to chunk could get lost?

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of `Chunk* chunk = _chunk;` if you then never use `_chunk` again and only use `chunk`? Why make a new variable?

Comment: presumably stack corruption somewhere, please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, it was stack related, hardly reproducable problem so no need for deeper explanation. That Chunk* chunk = _chunk I was just trying something out and havent removed all obsolete code.